# SAPUI5 List Bind Aggregation get Value of the list

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have list  and I am using bindaggregation to bind my model data.
below is my code.

**Controller**

```
this.oList = this.byId("list");     
this.oListItem = this.byId("MAIN_LIST_ITEM").clone();
this.oList.bindAggregation("items", {path: '/myListSet',
template: this.oListItem,
            filters: this.searchFilters,
        });
this.registerMasterListBind(this.oList);
console.log("firststatus"+this.oListItem.getFirstStatus().getText());   
}
```

My requirement is to manipulate the value of the firststatus, Fristly I am trying to get the value with the below line and unfortunately it is diplaying null value. Can someone advise how to get the value of the firststatus?

```
this.oListItem.getFirstStatus().getText()
```

**Update** - View

```
<List id="list" growing="true" growingThreshold="20" growingScrollToLoad="true" showNoData="true" mode="{device>/listMode}"
                select="_handleSelect">
                <ObjectListItem id="MAIN_LIST_ITEM" type="{device>/listItemType}" press="_handleItemPress" title="{sName}">
                    <markers>
                        <ObjectMarker type="Flagged"/>
                    </markers>
                    <firstStatus>
                        <ObjectStatus text="{Status1Txt}"/>
                    </firstStatus>
                    <attributes>
                        <ObjectAttribute id="ATTR1" text="{SNumber}"/>
                        <ObjectAttribute id="ATTR2" text="{PTxt}"/>
                    </attributes>
                    <secondStatus>
                        <ObjectStatus text="{Status2Txt}"/>
                    </secondStatus>
                </ObjectListItem>
            </List>
```

Comment: Could you add some view information, please?

Comment: Hi @MatthijsMennens I have updated the view, my idea is if I am able to retrieve the first status text, I want to write an if condition and destroy the markers. All I am struggling now is to retrieve the first status text in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you're trying to retrieve the status text of an entry, but what you're actually doing is retrieving the default template of the `ObjectListItem`.

If you want the correct value for an entry, you can try this. This returns a filled clone of the default template. You can't `clone()` an empty template and expect it to have values in it.

Hope this helps, lampstand.

```
this.byId("list").getItems()[0].getFirstStatus().getText();
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'getFirstStatus' of undefined Have tried this.getView().byId("list"). and this.byId....

Comment: Does your list have any entries?

Comment: If your list has entries, then this.byId("list").getItems() should not return undefined. Can you check that?

Comment: it is working , as always, thank you for your help Matthijs